# Finding encrypt for a decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I have legacy C# code that has an encrypted password in code, decrypts it and uses it. I now have to change the actual source value, i.e. the `base64` string needs to change.

Decryption code:

```
        var des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        var md5Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        des.Key = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(...key...));
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var desDecrypt = des.CreateDecryptor();
        var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(...value...);
        var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(desDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
        return result;
```

I am trying to do an ad-hoc re-encrypt of the changed value like this:

```
        var des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        var md5Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        des.Key = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(...key...));
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var desEncrypt = des.CreateEncryptor();
        var s = "...new value...";
        var b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
        desEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
        var x = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

This gives me a nice `base64` value to replace my old constant with. However, when the code tries to decrypt this new value, I get a

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the
>   data to decrypt is invalid.

The source values are of the same length. The base64 values are of the same length. I know this is no way to run a railroad. I'm just hoping that I am missing something obvious, easy and/or silly.

Comment: Is it public private key policy? If so there are different keys for encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Frankly, it's been so long since I've dealt with encryption that I don't know it from a hole in the ground. However, from the documentation it seems TripleDES is symmetrical, so I doubt that is it. Also note that there is no initialization vector set/used anywhere.

Comment: On a tangent: It seems like CipherMode.ECB [isn't so good to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx)

Comment: You get this error if the input of the method doing the decryption is not precisely a x times the blocksize, with x in Z (all positive numbers including 0. So your code to read in the value `value` is likely invalid.

Comment: I agree. However, compared to the other truck-sized security holes this particular implementation has, it is truly the least of my worries.

Comment: @owlstead: both source strings are 11 characters. Both byte buffers are 22 bytes. Both base64 strings are 32 characters.

Comment: Could you print out the size of `buffer`? It should be 24 bytes in length in that case.

Comment: I misspoke. The buffer is 24 when it works, and it is 22 when it doesn't. Do I have to null-terminate myself?

Comment: Maybe, that's outside the given code I presume. Somehow you've lost a couple of bytes. Oh, Iridium has already given the answer, you were using the plaintext

Comment: @owlstead: thank you. You actually led me to the answer Iridium gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually using the output of the 3DES encryption:

```
var b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
// This returns the encrypted data, but you're not storing it anywhere
desEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
// b is still the original input, not the encrypted data
var x = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

Try this:

```
var b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
// Store encrypted data in "e"
var e = desEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
// Convert the encrypted data to base64
var x = Convert.ToBase64String(e);
```

Comment: Oh FFS. Thank you so much. Now I guess we can close this question as "too localized".